# Custom cursor won't show in Chrome but works in Safari

Tags: html, css, cursor

I'm trying to use a custom cursor for my website. However, it only shows up on safari but not chrome. The website is online and the address is [www.p3k4800.com](http://www.p3k4800.com)
I'd really appreciate the help!
Thank you!!!

Here's the HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr" id="bleed">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Yuhan Hu</title>
    <style type="text/css">
body, html {
     cursor: url('c2.svg'),auto;
   }
</style>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
 <script src=app.js></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
   </head>
  <body class="homeindex" >

    <div class="mix">
 <img src="sources/work1.1.jpg" id="home_video">
    <!-- <video controls autoplay id="home_video">
      <source src="sources/1.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video> -->
<div class="texts">
      <h1  class = "title"> Yuhan Hu </h1>
    <ul class = "items">
      <li class="subs"><a href="sub/works1.html">Works.1</li>
      <li class="subs"><a href="sub/works2.html">Works.2</li>
      <li class="subs"><a href="sub/works3.html">Works.3</li>
      <li class="subs"><a href="sub/works4.html">Works.4</li>
      <li class="subs"><a href="sub/works5.html">Works.5</li>
      <li class="subs"><a href="sub/polaroids.html">Polaroids</li>
      <li class="subs"><a href="sub/videos.html">Videos</li>

      <br>
      <br>

     <li class="subs"><a href="sub/info.html">Contact</li>

      </ul>
    </div>
      </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

and here's the css cursor part

```
.title{
  color: white;
 mix-blend-mode: difference;
font-family: "MyWebFont" ;
font-weight: bolder;
position: relative;
left: 20px;
animation: neon .08s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
cursor: url('sources/c.svg')
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Did you see this in the Chrome console?

> [Deprecation] Custom cursors with size greater than 32x32 DIP
> intersecting native UI is deprecated and will be removed in M75,
> around June 2019. See
> https://www.chromestatus.com/features/5825971391299584 for more
> details.

DISCLAIMER: I can answer your question as to why its not working, but I do not claim to know what you can do to work around it, other than restrict your cursor to 32x32.

https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5825971391299584

> Custom cursors with widths or heights greater than 32 DIP will be
> removed if they intersect native UX (i.e. are not fully contained in
> the visual viewport).
>
> Large cursors are being used abusively on the web, to confuse users
> (see https://crbug.com/880863). Specifically, large custom cursors can
> be used to cover important (sometimes security related) browser native
> UX with an arbitrary image to mislead users into thinking they are
> clicking outside the content area.

Comment: Thank you! But how can you know the DIP?